# Weird result in pgRouting with Dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, mapserver

I'm using Dijkstra's algorithm to perform pgRouting with MapServer. I've stored the following function in PostGIS:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.routing_function(
IN x1 numeric,
IN y1 numeric,
IN x2 numeric,
IN y2 numeric)
RETURNS TABLE(seq integer, path_seq integer, node bigint, edge bigint, cost double precision, agg_cost double precision, street text, geom text) AS
$BODY$
WITH dijkstra AS(
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('SELECT id, source, target, time AS cost FROM road_network',
--source
(SELECT source FROM road_neetwork ORDER BY geom <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint($1, $2), 2100) ASC LIMIT 1),
--target
(SELECT target from road_network ORDER BY geom <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint($3, $4), 2100) ASC LIMIT 1),
-- undirected
false)  
),
the_geom AS(
SELECT dijkstra.*, b.street, ST_AsText(b.geom) FROM dijkstra INNER JOIN road_network AS b on dijkstra.edge = b.id
)    
  SELECT * FROM the_geom WHERE CASE WHEN 'source' != 'target' THEN true ELSE false END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
```

It's working and I'm getting a result. But I'm wondering if the result is reliable, because instead of "deciding" to travel around the city (yellow line) which is faster, as the "cost" is time, the algorithm takes me THROUGH the city, as shown in the picture (the arrow indicates the street with the desirable route and probably the fastest). Is it normal ?

[image: Routing result]

EDIT: One more example. The arrow indicates the desired route

[image]

And another one. Even more weird...!!!!

[image: Weird route from dijkstra's algorithm]

Comment: How did you made your topology? Maybe there is no intersection? Or maybe time is not well counted and according to data this way really is quickest?

Comment: I used pgr_createTopoology(). I wouldn't think there's a problem with time. The only possibility I can think is that the vertexes are not well snapped but again, if it failed an intersection, it would succeed the next one. This is a network that I have digitized. How can I check if the nodes are not snapped in QGIS? Topology checker maybe? (Sorry if this opens another question)

Comment: Hmm.... Maybe you're right about the time not having being well calculated. If I run Dijkstra's algorithm with 'time AS cost' the results are as expected. Is it a prerequisite that Dijkstra's algorithm must ALWAYS have 'time AS cost' ??

Comment: pgRouting algorithms just return you the route with the lowest cost, so for some reason the one you expect to be lower is either not properly connected or has too high costs assigned. You could try to visualize your cost attributes, nodes and road network in QGIS. Try to zoom in, where the route makes an unexpected turn, and see, if the roads are connected.

Comment: As @dkastl said, I can't see other option. You can select manually edges of your routes (this from routing, and this you think should be quickest) in QGIS, save selected in different files and count sum() of time - this will answer question if this is case of bad calculated time. Also you can check for every edge if they have one common vertice in source/target column - if no than they are not connected...

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Will give it a shot. One more thing: is it a prerequisite that the "cost" must only be time. Can I say "distance AS cost" for example ?

Comment: You can have anything as cost.